# How do you come to grips with the fact that you made a human being?

Tags: parents

I have recently turned 30 and all of a sudden the broodiness is hitting me like a ton of bricks. All my 20's I worked with children and did not pay them any mind, but all of a sudden a switch has been turned, and now I see fair-skinned, blonde children EVERYWHERE!

The fact that bothers me is how people have children like it is riding a bicycle. Personally, the prospect of bringing a child into this world frightens me. It is like the cabinet I made in woodshop class in High-School, but unlike the cabinet, the child is a living breathing person. It has feelings. It can breathe and feel pain. It is a complete sentient being. That I MADE *GASP*.

If you bring children into this world, you make them. Can you truly get your head around the fact THAT YOU MADE A HUMAN BEING? I'm struggling with the idea. Children are born innocent, but they dont stay like that for long.

How do I know if I would be a good parent? If you cannot be sure how good a parent you would be how can you bring a child into the world? There unfortunately are no taksey-bakseys on this. Sure the kid can die but once born the child cannot be unborn.

Can any parents please tell me how they came to grips with this? On the one hand, I deeply desire a family of my own, but I would just like to think that I'm too rational of a person to accept such a massive responsibility with so many unknowns.

Comment: Neil, I sympathize deeply with this question, but I don't think it's a parenting question until you actually have a baby (*parenting*). Until then, I think it's a philosophical issue. Maybe it would be on-topic on Philosophy? I don't know. Everyone has to make this decision for themselves, and grapple with the consequences. There are parents who had all manner of reasons to become so, with all manner of reactions. No one else's reasons should influence your own; it's too big an issue.

Comment: If you desire answers, please take this to meta and ask if it can be reopened, or why it was closed. The community can decide then if this is on-topic or not. Or, you can ask for studies of it from a parenting viewpoint (are there studies about how many parents regret having children and why? or something similar.)

Comment: You might also be interested in books like "The Baby Dilemma" which help guide you through the potential upsides and downsides of having a kid. They might help ease your angst, or make you decide that you can't justify having a kid based on how you feel.